# how configure digitalocean server with bigrock domain name

Tags: dns, hostname, nameservers, server-configuration, digital-ocean

Hi friends.

I am a new user for server setup. Please, help me to configure DigitalOcean server with my Bigrock domain name.

My domain name is www.myclass.in

my BigRock domain IP address is 192.142.134.157

I have purchased a 5 dollar plan(ubuntu 12.04) on DigitalOcean for the server and its IP address is 100.170.153.128.

I tried some steps to add a domain name in DNS menu of DigitalOcean etc, but it is not working. So, please help me.

Please also tell me, if any changes into apache files.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1:

Create a Droplet on the Digital ocean .

Step 2 :

After you add your domain name on DNS of Digital ocean . Type the domain name and enter the ip address of the server you want to host your domain
!
Add your domain name in the Box with >> Name
Add ip address of your server (reffered as droplet on Digital Ocean ) you created .
OR

You can select the droplet directly after the given box beside Ip address as “SELECT A DROPLET”

Step3:

Now move on to the you bigrock account and open your domain settings for which you want to configure the server .

Step4:

Open the name servers on the settings and replace the nameservers names with your server name servers and then click ok . Please note that at least two nameservers must be configured on it .

Add the name servers of the digtal ocean you see in DNS settings of Digital ocean

Step5:

Now Move onto DNS settings and change the A name records with your host ip address and click ok also see that if any changes to be done with Cnames , Mx records , Txt etc and save them . if applicable .